# Javascript, add event listener to all buttons

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to add event listeners to all of the buttons in an HTML document. When a button is pressed I'd like to display a simple alert. 
My code, which isn't working at the moment, follows:

```
var bns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

function addtoev() {
  for (i = 0; i < bns.length; i++) {
    bns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("you clicked"); 
    });
   }
}
```

It definitely works as such in JSFiddle by calling the method or eliminating the function line, but it's still not executing in Chrome (popups are not blocked). I post my HTML, is it possible that buttons nested in a table need to be referenced differently than buttons alone?

```
  <tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>
  <td>john@doe.us</td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-default">X</button></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: when and how are you calling `addtoev` method?

Comment: Works just fine, if you call `addtoev()` ... http://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/zdfg2107/

Comment: or, simply, remove `function addtoev(){` row... and, of course, last `}`.

Comment: Make sure to use `for (var i = 0`... otherwise you're leaking a global.

Comment: Added the HMTL if anyone could have a look. Thanks.

Comment: The issue is still that you actually need to call `addtoev`. That has nothing to do with your HTML. *"is it possible that buttons nested in a table need to be referenced differently than buttons alone?"* No.

Comment: Thanks, yes, have tried calling it but didn't change the results (although as mentioned it does work in JSFiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my problems were stemming from the fact that I was loading my JS file in the header, before all of the buttons were loading. I now have it working by loading my JS at the end of the body.

Answer (score 4):

you need to listen of the load event, like this:

```
function addtoev() {
  var bns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  for (i = 0; i < bns.length; i++) {
    bns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("you clicked"); });
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  addtoev();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

better to use JQuery:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="button1" value="button1" />
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="button2" value="button2" />
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="button3" value="button3" />

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(":button").click(function (event) {
                alert(event.target.id + ' is click!');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure it is but I'm a student tasked with doing everything the "hard way" as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should call the method `addtoev()`

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/jkc74ywx/)

```
var bns = $("button");
bns.on("click", function() {
    alert("you clicked");
});
```